# Cannot get Character Encodings right with rtweet and RMeCab tokenizer

Tags: r, utf-8, character-encoding, rtweet, mecab

I am trying to text mine Japanese Tweets and am running into seemingly unsolvable Issues with character encodings.

After mining the tweets and setting locale with `Sys.setlocale("LC_ALL", "Japanese_Japan.932")` I get a dataframe that looks as expected:

[image]

I want to run these Tweets through a Tokenizer for Japanese language, namely `RMeCab`, based on `MeCab` ([all available here](https://taku910.github.io/mecab/)). `MeCab`can be compiled in `UTF-8`, `SHIFT-JIS` and a few others, but recompiling in another encoding doesn't make my problem go away or even change the end result.

So, after compiling `MeCab` and installing `RMeCab`, I extract the first tweet and try to tokenize it with

```
tweet1 <- trump_ja[1,5]
x <- RMeCabC(str = tweet1)
```

This yields the following output:

[image]

These are unfortunately not the correct Japanese Characters. I have tried the following alternations between `SHIFT-JIS` and `UTF-8` encoding (and all combinations of these changes) to overcome this problem:

- Open the R Script with different encoding (makes a difference, but just shows different garbled characters, so I'm assuming the garbling happens within RMeCab)
- Switch locale between `Sys.setlocale("LC_ALL", "English_United States.1252")` and `Sys.setlocale("LC_ALL", "Japanese_Japan.932")`
- Recompile MeCab in a different encoding

I am now at the end of the line and would like to ask for help.

EDIT:
I have now figured out that running an `iconv (result, from = "UTF8", to = "UTF-8")` conversion on a tokenized (and garbled) character string shows me the correct Japanese characters for the tokens. This doesn't see to make a lot of sense, but it does the trick. However, I'd like to avoid this extra step, as the conversion only works on character strings, and not on lists or vectors.

Comment: I just installed RMecabC and `x <- RMeCabC(str="私は田中です。")` works as expected. I didn't run `setlocale`: `Sys.getlocale()` returns `en_US.UTF-8`. Do you get garbled output if you set your locale to this and parse a plain string literal? (On macOS I cannot run your `setlocale` command, R says `OS reports request to set locale to "Japanese_Japan.932" cannot be honored`, sorry.)

Comment: (My MeCab was compiled for UTF-8 (the only sane choice).)

Comment: Unfortunately, `en_US.UTF-8` is not available on Windows, which is where the whole tragedy begins. However, `Japanese_Japan.932` is a UTF-8 locale, so it should theoretically amount to the same as `en_US.UTF-8`. To answer your question: The plain text string with `Japanese_Japan.932` returns garbled output in list `x`.

Comment: Understood… I'm still curious, what happens if you try to parse a plain sting literal, e.g., `RMeCabC(str="私は田中です。")`?

Comment: Ah, sorry I misunderstood your question. The output is still garbled: `[[1]]險伜捷 "私は\x93" [[2]] 蜷崎ｩ\x9e  "c" `

Comment: It's so suspicious that `iconv(result, "UTF8", "UTF-8")` does anything meaningful, let alone ungarbles! The iconv doc says "UTF8" is converted to "UTF-8" internally so, what on earth is going on. I suspect it's plain R that's messing up the encoding on its way to RMecab but I don't have a Windows box to test. Sorry.

Comment: If that's the case, then `setlocale` or reopening the file in another encoding should take care of it, no? It's so sad because I am trying to teach my students text analysis with R and I'm sure that after this nightmare none of them are ever going to want to use it again...